# Calculating "% of Total" for Users metric in Data Studio yields results greater than 100%

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to show the % of users who completed a task on our website, there are four possible outcomes, so I want to break down the % of total for users who completed each. Looking at my table in Data Studio, the % add up to >100%, yet the actual User numbers are the same numbers I'm seeing in Google Analytics. I also have Total Events and % of total for Total Events in the table, everything runs smooth there, the four outcomes % adds up to 100% like it should.

What can I do to fix this? My metric is Users and the Type is "percent" and the Comparison Calculation is "percent of total".

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Data Studio dedupes the Users. So in this case, users were able to fail and then succeed in these instances, so Data Studio was actually accounting for those who had failed and then gone on to succeed, hence the >100%. It took the one Users event # and divided by the total to then get the Users %.